How to run a for loop for RandomFunction in order to take an aggregate of trajectories to approximate the steady state?
I am trying to approximate the steady state for the given rate matrix:

By using the ContinuousMarkovProcess function and the RandomFunction process. I want to implement some sort of for loop system that generates a number of random trajectories for the rate matrix, so I can take the average of the trajectories and receive a solution for the steady state. I also would like to plot this sum of trajectories to show the physical relaxation to the steady state. So far, I'm only able to plot one trajectory. Any ideas? This is my current code:
R = {{-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, -2 + \[Epsilon],
     1 + \[Epsilon], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1 - \[Epsilon], -2 - \[Epsilon], 1,
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, -2, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1}};
rule = {\[Epsilon] -> 0.5};
ra = Transpose[R /. rule];

state = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Rho] = ContinuousMarkovProcess[state, ra];
select = {1 -> {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 2 -> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   3 -> {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 4 -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
   5 -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 6 -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

\[Psi] = RandomFunction[\[Rho], {0, 50, 1}]

ListPlot[\[Psi], Filling -> Axis, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}]

traces = 
 Total[Table[Transpose[Normal[\[Psi]][[1]]][[2]] /. select, {n, 50}]/
   50]

ListLinePlot[{traces[[All, 1]], traces[[All, 2]], traces[[All, 3]], 
  traces[[All, 4]], traces[[All, 5]], traces[[All, 6]]}] 

Any hints or tips are appreciated.

RandomFunction has another argument n where you can make an ensemble of many paths - you don't need a loop.

Building on @flinty's comment, here's a way to plot the results:
\[Psi] = RandomFunction[\[Rho], {0, 50, 1}, 1000];
dat = Transpose[\[Psi][50][[2, {2, 1}]]];
ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> {{0.9, 6.1}, {0, All}}]


\[Psi][50] is a DataDistribution type Empirical.  Maybe there's a more elegant way to get the probability mass data out than \[Psi][50][[2, {2, 1}]] but that seems to work.
